# Pair of straight line

Tags: geometry

Today I learnt about pair of lines or homogeneous pair of lines then I decide to plot a equation on desmos randomly
When I put the equation $4 x²+12 x y+10 y²=0$  then this happens..
[Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dve8p0uwcb)
I want some explaination on it

> what do you call this equation of line?

> Is it shows a line only at origin?

`If there is any loophole(s) in question framing please let me know before downvoting.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You equation is
$$
4x^2+12xy+10 y^2 = 0\Leftrightarrow (2x+3y)^2+y^2=0
$$

and this is only possible when
$$
y = 0, \quad 2x+3y = 0,
$$

which means that the equation defines a single point, $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this .